# In need of app to create GUI's for Linux

Tags: gui

I currently develop android apps using Eclipse, and I was curious if there was something I can install that will allow me to do the same for Linux. I don't plan to hit the ground running, but I was simply intrigued by the idea of creating a GUI that could unpack tarballs as little project.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create GUI application in Ubuntu you should have a look at [Ubuntu Developer APIs](http://developer.ubuntu.com/apps/qml/api/).

But for simple GUI app written in C++, I will suggest you to use [Qt](http://qt-project.org/). It also provide a lightweight IDE  called 
[QTCreator](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/qtcreator/) [image: Install QTCreator]
 which has C++, QML and ECMAscript support.